# dynamic HTML String to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would be getting dynamic html content from my template rendering which was rendered by other react components. How would I convert this html string to React component so that I can use the component in my render function. Note that I want to preserve react specific attributes used for diffing.

```js
React.createClass( {
  var self = this;

  componentWillMountDown : function() {
    //htmlString is essentially huge dynamic one in my actual case
    var htmlString = "<div class='classDiv' react-id="0.1"><input type='text'/></div>";
    self.setState({responseString : htmlString});
    self.forceUpdate();
  },
    
  render: function() {
    var Response = this.state.responseString;
    //how would I return the react component as response?
    return (<Response/>); //does not work. err is it shd be valid react component
   }
});
```

I've tried converting htmlString to HTMLDocument object and recursively creating React.createElement in willmount callback and setting react component. however, the error is type toUpperCase is not defined.

Answer (score 13):

A few hours ago, I published an `html-to-react` module in npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react) that may help you.

Please let me know if there's anything you need, I can certainly work with you to make the module more flexible.

Comment: How can I use htm-to-react in an Asp.Net MVC project? Looked over internet but cant find a simple answer to it.

Comment: You'll likely have to configure ReactJS.net to use webpack, which is a royal pain.  See: https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html - After trying this approach and succeeding (after a few days' work) I had the Asp.Net MVC project modified to use a RESTful API and ported the front-end to create-react-app

Comment: An answer should not just be a link, it should show the code required to answer the question

Comment: This is useful. Thanks. Although the change of states inside mentioned components are not getting rerendered even though I'm using usestate. Any Help?

Answer (score 9):

Because you store your component as string so you have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. This is my suggestion. I hope someone else will have the better answer. :)

```
    render: function() {
    var self = this;
    var Response = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
        return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: self.state.responseString}}></div>)
        }
    });
    return (
            <Response />
    )
   }
```

Comment: Just edited the question. Since I want to preserve react specific attributes I won't be able to use dangerously SetInnerHtml. Is there a programmatic way of creating react components from HTML string

Answer (score 2):

You can use React HTML Parser. Here is the link [React HTML Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

It's a utility for converting HTML strings into React components. Avoids the use of dangerouslySetInnerHTML and converts standard HTML elements, attributes and inline styles into their React equivalents.