# How to convert a string into React element- ReactJs/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I crated a react html element like:

```
let elements = (
      <div>
        <div>dwewe</div>
        <div>wefwef</div>
        <span>yurhfjer</span>
      </div>

    );
```

and now I wanted to pass this to an html attribute, hence I converted the react element into string using:

```
<span data-tip-react={ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)}>{title}></span>
```

I'm now able to access these elements, however I'd like to convert it back to react element (the way it was before conversion)
here is what I'm expecting the o/p as:

[image]

I tried using DOMParser, however it returned an html element that React did not accept for rendering and threw an errr: not a react element

How do I convert the string back into the same format - React element??
please help!
thanks

Comment: can you show this part 
```I tried using DOMParser, however it returned an html element that React did not accept for rendering and threw an errr: not a react element```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following here :

[dynamic HTML String to react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715220/dynamic-html-string-to-react-component)

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (for simple element) or some npm package :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  getDom() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>dwewe</div>
        <div>wefwef</div>
        <span>yurhfjer</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  convertToString(dom) {
    console.log("To String", ReactDOMServer.renderToString(dom))
    return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(dom)
  }

  convertToDOM(string) {
    let domparser = new DOMParser();
    console.log("To Dom", domparser.parseFromString(string, 'text/html'))
    return domparser.parseFromString(string, 'text/html')​​
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
          {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.convertToString(this.getDom())}}></div>}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ex : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mhsqfd

Comment: Thanks for the solution: This is what I tried for DOM purify: ```let parser = new DOMParser();
let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent, 'text/html')``` and I'm trying to render it as react HTML for which I get this error:

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__html}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: also is there any alternative for using ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML```, this is prone to xxs attacks and we are suing sanitize in our app for purifying any html tag strings..so I'm sure if this will work.. :(

Comment: @user1234 sorry for the delay, do you still have the problem? If so can you make a quick stackblitz so that it is easier to understand ?

Comment: When you say `I'm trying to render it as react HTML` do you mean you tried to do something like `<MyParsedHtml></MyParsedHtml>`

Comment: Then the fast way would be to use something like  `react-jsx-parser` or do by hand the convertion to react code using babel like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx