# React Component is not rendering and returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, template-literals

I have to prepare one static HTML and inside it, I have to render a react Link. But it is not working as expected and returns [object Object].
Here is my code.

```
 const htmlCode =    `<div class='info-container'>
                          <div class='heading-section'>
                              ${<><Link to = {targetURL}>Click Here</Link></>}
                          </div>
                      <div>`
```

Output I am getting after rendering:

[image]

[image]

I have consoled that  and getting output on console as shown below :

[image]

------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------

The main goal here is, I want to pass this static HTML (variable htmlCode) to another component and that  is not rendering but I get object instead of rendered  as shown in console output attached here. Is there any way I can render that and convert it to a kind of static HTML before passing to other component?

Answer (score 2):

JSX is not HTML, it is a syntactic sugar for HTML. You cannot wrap it around strings. It will transpile to `React.createElement` which returns a JavaScript object.

```
const htmlCode = <div class='info-container'>
                     <div class='heading-section'>
                         <Link to = {targetURL}>Click Here</Link>
                      </div>
                  <div>
```

See more of [Rendering JSX elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)

Comment: Tried this solution, [object Object] was removed and get the correct string there but Link is not rendered yet as expected, see the rendered Link component here [link](https://prnt.sc/26ixw7w)

Comment: `Link`, Is it from react-router-dom?

Comment: Yes, It is from react-router-dom

Comment: the screenshot looks like you've used `link` instead of `Link`, `Link` from router will render a `<a>` tag

Comment: you can also replace `Link` with `<a href={targetURL}>Click Here</a>`

Comment: that will result in the page reloading :(

Comment: I have edited the question, maybe you can have a more clear idea about what I want to achieve

Comment: check if this is helpful , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715220/dynamic-html-string-to-react-component?rq=1